# Export search results to Excel and PDF

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

We need to export the search results we get in Share into an Excel and PDF file. How can we achieve that?

Comment: Like your other Question [Allow users to save queries/search parameters in Alfresco Share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893335/export-search-results-to-excel-and-pdf): It would be possible to catch the query or search hit list but Alfresco never provided an extension point in Share to add your requested functionality.

Comment: Does this extension point exist in the digital workspace app?

Comment: no - as far as I know there is no such thing in the "Alfresco Content Application". Please check [Extensibility features](https://alfresco-content-app.netlify.app/#/extending/extensibility-features)